# Passing 2 input strings to compare

Tags: c

I'm testing a small program which basically compares whether 2 input strings are identical (as strcmp does).

I'd want to do something like (users type 2 desired strings on the same line). In this case it should return "The two strings are different"

```
./a.out foo bar
```

should I do this to read the user's input strings?

```
 scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
```

or

```
gets(str1); gets(str2);
```

Here is what I have so far (it seems to stuck in an infinite loop for some reasons)

```
int mystrcmp(char str1[], char str2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str1[i] == str2[i]) {
        if (str1[i] == '\0' || str2[i] == '\0') break;
        i++;
    }
    if (str1[i] == '\0' && str2[i] == '\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char * * argv) {
    int cmp;
    char str1[1000], str2[1000];
    scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
    //gets(str1); gets(str2);
    cmp = mystrcmp(str1, str2);
    if (cmp == 0)
        printf("The two strings are identical.\n");
    else
        printf("The two strings are different.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The strings passed in the command line are passed in `argv`.

Comment: For the record, you should usually use `fgets` instead of `gets` to prevent buffer overflow.  What if I wrote two 1001 character words that differed on the last letter? Your program wouldn't be able to handle that.  `fgets` lets you set the number of characters to read to be safe (which should be 1 less than the total size of your buffer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 3) {
        puts("Wrong number of arguments");
        return 0;
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[1], argv[2]))
        puts("The two strings are different.");
    else
        puts("The two strings are identical.");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should do neither. Instead I suggest you learn about how command line arguments are passed to the `main` function through the `argc` and `argv` arguments.

I suggest you try this program to help your understanding:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);

    for (int a = 0; a < argc; ++a)
        printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", a, argv[a]);
}
```

For your example invocation

```
./a.out foo bar
```

the program above will print

```
argc = 3
argv[0] = "./a.out"
argv[1] = "foo"
argv[2] = "bar"
```

Comment: I see. So do I pass the first input string thourgh `argv[1]` and second through `argv[2]` ?

Comment: Yes. And always check `argc` for the correct number of parameters. Otherwise you will likely  get some segfaults.

Comment: `argv` is an array of `char *`s.  Each element points to a string.

Comment: @Walle Yes those two entries in the arrays contain pointers to the first two arguments. However, always check that you have the correct number or arguments (in your case `argc` should be at least `3`).