# C code a bit difficult?

Tags: c, pointers

My goal: understand the following code

What I currently understand: when you compile, you pass an int and pointer to a pointer

signal() does the following http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_signal.htm
which is a little difficult for me to understand.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
        signal(SIGFPE, word);
}
```

Comment: sorry but I don't get it at all - please rewrite the question to first explain what you want to do

Comment: I thought a "bit difficult" was a pun :)

Comment: Have you tried to read *any* book or tutorial on C? In that case you would understand what the `main` function does and how you call it (or rather, how *you* don't call it).

Comment: _"i am not sure how to pass that"_. You're not supposed to call the `main` function; that's done for you.

Comment: Ooh! You're asking about `main`, not `signal`! ... I think.

Comment: Also, wait with more advanced concepts (like signals and pointers to functions) until you know the basics and how to handle normal pointers.

Comment: wait pass pointer to pointer argument in main function through command prompt

Comment: If you want to learn how to handle command line arguments, see e.g. [this recent answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32404308/440558).

Answer (score 1):

While in principle [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) is standardized by C99, in practice it is provided by operating system specific services. `signal` is given a function pointer as its second argument (the signal handler, `word` in your case).

On Linux, read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) before using the `signal` function.

The `main` function is very special (in hosted C implementations). It is given an argument count and an array of program argument strings. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26534525/841108) for details. The execution of your program starts at `main` (and how that happens is implementation specific, read about [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0))

Comment: And, + Or it could even be replaced by `int main(void){...}` depending upon if the parameters aren't to be passed from the command line.

Comment: But this should be avoided IMHO. Users (and specially beginners) should be taught to always define `int main(int argc, char**argv)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my upvote here. Apologies for being late, BTW, I forgot to mention that I'm a fan of yours because of your answering style. :)